# Unable to detect emulator when `react-native run-android` command is ran in Apple MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Chip

Tags: android, react-native, apple-m1

I have started doing react-native development in MacBook Pro M1. Since it is using Apple M1 Chip I have installed [android emulator m1 preview](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.3). Emulator is running and opened project in studio. If I run `react-native run-android` command from terminal I am getting following error,

> error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.

But if I run the app from studio by tapping on "Run app" then app runs successfully in emulator.

1.Is this how usually it works that `react-native run-android` command won't work in Apple MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Chip?

OR

2.Do I have do any configuration changes according to M1 Processor machine?

Comment: Please note that early release M1 versions of the full Android Studio are now available, and they have the M1 Emulator properly integrated so you don't need that standalone one any more.  I'm running Android Studio - Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 2.  Be warned that this is bleeding edge stuff, but working fine for me so far for a React Native app.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on my M1 and found the solution by following [these steps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

The official documentation recommends using `npx react-native run-android`.

Before installing [android emulator m1](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview) I installed adb separately.

```
brew install android-platform-tools
```

Then see the emulator after execute

```
 adb devices
```

I hope it helps.